# Laptop detects wifi network but can't connect

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, drivers

I have a netbook that has the Realtek RTL8192E wireless adapter and when running Windows 7 starter it detects my home network that has WEP security but will never connect to it after restarting the pc and resetting the adapter. Ethernet does work fine when directly connected to my router. Also important to note that this netbook also has Windows 8 installed and it has the same symptom, detects my network but will never connect. All other devices in my house are able to connect to the same network, and location doesn't matter.

Current driver version is 1676.1.622.2009

Driver date is 6/22/2009

Windows tells me this is the most recent driver update but I have to think the driver has been updated since then.

Is this most likely a driver problem or some type of problem with my network.

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Sidenote : **don't use WEP**, [it can be cracked in minutes](http://superuser.com/q/733081/256743).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, however my question is not about network security.

Comment: Can you connect to other networks ?

Comment: Unfortunately I only have 1 network in my home and don't have another network to test with.

Comment: Try different parameters for the network, even try to disable encryption (but only for a quick test and make sure you don't have anything vulnerable on your network or passwordless file shares).