# Asus router how to disable reset button

Tags: router, reset, parental-controls

I am trying to set parental control on an Asus router. However, my son always reset my router to change the parental setting. Is that anyway that I can disable the reset button?

Comment: The most reliable solution would require a little bit of help from the ISP. If the router needed a password in order to authenticate towards the ISP, then resetting it would presumably wipe the password as well. In that case the password would be needed in order to get online again.

Comment: If your son knows how to reset a router it won't take him long to discover the wonderful worlds of Tor and VPNs which can breach even the most restrictive firewalls (the only solution would be to only allow communications to whitelisted servers). And even once you disconnect Internet completely, he can still get it from his phone, or by [breaking into a poorly secured network](http://superuser.com/questions/733081/is-it-really-possible-for-most-enthusiasts-to-crack-peoples-wi-fi-networks/) or just asking the neighbors. This is a parenting/human issue, no amount of technology will solve it.

Comment: As @AndréDaniel said, this is a parenting issue. You might want to consider asking for some advice about how to deal with your son's behavior on http://parenting.stackexchange.com/. It would be very on topic there. (Just make sure to check for a similar question before posting.)

Answer (score 9):

Some options:

1. Unplug the router, open it, [desolder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desoldering) the button and remove it from the circuit board.
2. Plug the hole with something permanent (epoxy).
3. Place the router someplace your son doesn't have access to (locked cabinet).
4. Ground him.

Comment: +1 for option nr 4 - *you can't effectively solve a psychological problem with an engineering solution*

Answer (score 1):

You could always try filling the hole with glue, [Sugru](https://sugru.com) etc (though that's a bit expensive for the microdot size you'd need)